# mysql identified by unix_socket behaves strange under sudo

Tags: mysql

I have set up my DB user on a server by `CREATE USER myuser IDENTIFIED VIA unix_socket;` and of course `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`. It works fine, I can connect to the database using `mysql` command.

Then I SSHed into the server as `myuser`, run `sudo su anotheruser` (who doesn't have his mysql account) and just to test thinks run `mysql`. I expected it to fail, but instead I got a mysql shell. I was confused, so a ran `SELECT USER();` and it returned `myuser@localhost`.

What does it mean? How could Linux `anotheruser` logged into mysql as `myuser`? Is `unix_socket` a secure way of authenticating user?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It still knows what user you are, originally, even across sudo su:

> `[rubio@craptop ~]$ sudo su - root`
>   `[sudo] password for rubio:`
>   `[root@craptop ~]# whoami`
>   `root`
>   `[root@craptop ~]# who am i`
>   `rubio    pts/1        2016-12-24 22:35 (:0)`

If the "real" login user is `anotheruser` it'll use that as the MySQL auth user.

Comment: How does `sudo mysql` work? If I type it, the DB believes I am `root` even if the "real" user is `myuser`?